# Electron app reactivate window using Tray Icon

Tags: electron

when we Minimize the application, how reactive the window by using Tray menu

```
const tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, '/assets/icons/commusoft-squarelogo.png'))
  const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: 'Active', type:'normal',role: 'front', click:try_click() },
    { label: 'Preferences', type: 'normal',click: try_click()},
    { label: 'Reload', type: 'normal', role: 'reload'},
    { label: 'Reload new', type: 'normal', role: 'reload'},
    { label: 'Quit', type: 'normal', role: 'quit' }
  ])
  tray.setToolTip('This is my application.')
  tray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now finally figure out the answer

```
const contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    { label: 'Active', type:'normal',role: 'front', click:function(){
                                                            win.show()
                                                      } 
    },
    { label: 'Preferences', type: 'normal',click: try_click()},
    { label: 'Reload', type: 'normal', role: 'reload'},
    { label: 'Reload new', type: 'normal', role: 'reload'},
    { label: 'Quit', type: 'normal', role: 'quit' }
  ])
```